# How to read html content of Ajax based site

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to know how the HTML source of ajax based sites can be read using HttpWebRequest / HttpWebResponse (That is reading the contents of a website at server side). The problem that I'm facing is that I'm unable to read parts of the webpage which uses Ajax or stuffs like UpdatePanel.

My application is in ASP.NET / C#, so can't think of using stuffs like Browser control or mshtml.dll since I would not be able to serve multiple requests.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're trying to achieve... Do you want to read the HTML contents on the client side (using JavaScript), or do you want to read the contents server side using C#? Or do you want to implement your own AJAX handlers without relying on the update panel's JavaScript trickery?

Comment: the basic answer is you'd have to be able to parse and execute the javascript yourself. as to *how*, I don't have a clue.

Comment: Ajax is making multiple requests by definition.  That's what makes it Ajax.  I'm not sure what you mean by you "would not be able to serve multiple requests"?

Comment: I would like to read the contents of a website at server side. Thats why I had mentioned in the post "using HttpWebRequest / HttpWebResponse". The problem here is that the html contents of sites are AJAX based doesn't appear. Try this open a AJAX site, take its html using "View Source" and try to find any content that is inside the update panel. You won't be able to see it.

Comment: You'll see it if you view the rendered source.  You don't see it in the initial source sent by the server because there wasn't anything to see UNTIL the "Ajax" kicked in and made a separate call to the server to fill in the panel.

Do you understand that HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse make additional calls to the server to get more content?  I'm still unclear as to exactly what your question is.

Answer (score 0):

this is going to be difficult.

I know you said you don't want to use Browser control, but I'm going to say it anyway. You will most probably be better off using a Browser control. The reasons are as follow:

1. AJAX sites make multiple calls from the browser to the server to obtain the required view.
2. The multiple calls are being performed via JavaScript
3. The data returned from the server may be reformatted by JavaScript before being updated onto the view.

If you are going to do this using HttpWebXyz functions, you will have to do the following:

1. Make the relevant calls to get the initial page source.
2. Parse the page for JavaScript.
3. Evaluate/execute the JavaScript. This may include providing the relevant implementation for functions such as `alert` and making subsequent calls to the server.

Depending on the complexity of the AJAX site, you may want to reconsider using the browser control. Complex sites are easier process by the control. If the site is simple enough, you may survive parsing and executing the required JavaScript.

[This example](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/10688.aspx) uses a deprecated class to parse JavaScript.

You may want to explore [ICodeCompiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.icodecompiler.aspx) and its relevant classes for the new approach.

Good luck.